# Vue.js - how to scroll to a parent "ref" division from a child method?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, dom, components, scrollto

Here I am asking for your help...I want to scroll within a page. The page is rendered by the parent component, that include some child component where the scrollTo method is defined.

I have a parent component - LandingPage.vue

```
<script>

import InPageAnchor from '@/Components/Navigation/Buttons/InPageAnchor.vue';

export default {

  components: {
    InPageAnchor,
  },
};
</script>

<template>
   <InPageAnchor/> <!-- is a button with the scrollTo method -->
   <div ref="scrollHere" >
   </div>
</template>
```

and here the child component: InPageAnchor.vue

```
<script>

export default {

  methods: {

      scrollTo: function () {
        
        this.$parent.$refs.scrollHere.$el.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth'}) //this.$parent.$refs.scrollHere.$el is undefined
      },
  }
}
</script>

<template>
    <button
        type = "button"
        class = "rounded-md my-1 px-2 w-1/6 bg-teal-600 hover:border-violet-700 hover:border-x-4 hover:bg-teal-700/75"
        @click = "scrollTo()">
        {{ text }}
      </button>  
</template>
```

There is a bit more behind the use of the child, and also the "scrollHere" is in fact given as props...

Thank you

Let me know if you want any additional details

LN

Comment: The use of $parent is bad design. A child shouldn't be aware of a parent. When sibling components need to interact, this means that there should be a parent that provides the interaction. In this case InPageAnchor should possibly be a parent and accept scrollable children through slots

Comment: Merci @EstusFlask - I'll change my code patern.